# Is there a name for functions $f$ such that $f\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be a measure space
and let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.

Suppose that the measure
\begin{equation*}
(f\mu)(A) = \int_A f(\omega)\mu(d\omega),\quad A\in\mathscr{F},
\end{equation*}
is $\sigma$-finite.
Is there a name for such functions $f$
that captures this property of $f\mu$ being $\sigma$-finite?
I am not aware of one.

If $f\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite,
then there are measurable sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ such that
$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}A_n = \Omega$
and for each $n$
\begin{equation*}
(f\mu)(A_n) = \int_{A_n} f(\omega)\mu(d\omega) < \infty.
\end{equation*}
Intuitively this would suggest to me calling $f$ *locally integrable*,
but this phrase is already reserved for
[something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function).
Another suggestion that comes to mind is *$\sigma$-integrable*,
but judging from a quick view on wikipedia/Google scholar/the web this is not a thing.